# can i overriding tesorflow serving method?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I want simply receives text input and tries to return only the label value among the predicted results.

Ex.
curl -d '{"inputs":{"test": ["I am very sad today"]}}' 
-X POST http://{location}:predict

and I want to get the return value "sad"

so I saw [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/deploying-a-text-classifier-with-tensorflow-serving-docker-in-2-0-cba6851e46ed) and tried it.

When saving the model, it was saved with decorate tf.function

```
self.tf_model_wrapper = TFModel(model)
tf.saved_model.save(self.tf_model_wrapper.model, f'classifier/saved_models/{int(time.time())}',
                          signatures={'serving_default': self.tf_model_wrapper.prediction})
```

and the function simply receives text and tokenizes it, and then tried to return the predicted result value to the label name.

```
@tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=(1, ), dtype=tf.string)])
def prediction(self, text: str):
    input_ids, input_attention, input_token_type = self.tokenizer(text)
    input_encoding = (input_ids, input_attention, input_token_type)
    result = self.convert_label(self.model(input_encoding))
    return result
```

but i got this error

```
TypeError: tf__prediction() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'input2' and 'input3'
```

I thought it was because my model receives 3 inputs, so I modified it like this and it seemed to work.

```
@tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=None, dtype=tf.int32, 
                              name="input_ids"),tf.TensorSpec(shape=None, dtype=tf.int32, 
                              name="attention_mask"),tf.TensorSpec(shape=None, dtype=tf.int32, name="token_type_ids")])
def prediction(self, input1, input2, input3):
    input = (input1, input2, input3)
    return self.model(input)
```

However, this is different from the original purpose and It seems impossible to receive only text and return predict results.

Is there any way I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tensorflow serving via the saved model seems to only provide inference. Therefore, i will have to configure the logic separately by building the server and REST API.